# Proof of the Principle of Backwards Induction

Tags: induction, peano-axioms

I'm trying to prove the following proposition, where "++" denotes the successor function (i.e., 2++ = S(2) = 3).

Let $n$ be a natural number, and let $P(m)$ be a property pertaining
to the natural numbers such that whenever $P(m++)$ is true, then $P(m)$
is true. Suppose that $P(n)$ is also true. Then $P(m)$ is true for all natural numbers $m \leq n$.

I'd be thankful if someone could check my proof and also clarify a particular step. The proof is quite verbose, but I like it that way. I'll post an image, because it gives me less headache to post my attempt:

[image]

I'm most worried about (5) of the induction step. It's obvious that it's correct, but at this point it's of course all about showing things rigorously that are "obviously true". But I'm failing at giving an explicit argument for why this step holds. I'm thankful for all feedback, especially concerning this precise issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that step 5 in the inductive step proof is not a purely logical step.

But note that step 4 of the inductive base is likewise also not purely logical, given that line $3$ refers to $\geq$ and line $4$ to $\leq$. So, if you don’t want to accept this step 4 on purely mathematical grounds, then you need to point out some connection between $\leq$ and $\geq$.

For example, we could add something like $\forall x \forall y ((x \leq y \land x \geq y) \to x=y)$ (Lemma1)

Then once we have $P(0)$ and $\forall x \ x \geq 0$, we can do for the Inductive Base:

$1. P(0)$

$2. \forall x \ x \geq 0$

$3. \forall x ((x \leq 0 \land x \geq 0) \to x=0)$ (Instance of Lemma1)

$4. \forall x (x \leq 0 \to x=0) \ (2,3)$

$5. \forall x (x \leq 0 \to P(x)) \ (1,4)$

You'd need to do something similar for the step 5 in the inductive Step part of the inductive proof, because you are right: going from 1 to 4 is obvious mathematically, but it doesn't follow purely logically. So you'd need to provide some further Lemma, definition, or what have you. And that's what Mark Saving tried to do in their Answer: Mark proposed to use

$\forall x \forall y (x \leq y++ \to (x \leq y \lor x = y++))$ (Lemma2)

And hopefully you can see how line 5 is the logical result of lines 2, 4, and Lemma2.

Now, of course you can ask where these Lemmas come from ... and don't you need to prove those?  Well, that all depends on what we consider our very axioms and definitions. I see that in your posted proof of the Inductive Base there is a reference to 'Definition 2' and 'Definition 4', so that might give you a clue.

Comment: Thank you for this. (: I was completely blind to the logical gap in the Induction Base, but as I had proven the Lemma you suggest anyways, it was easy to fix. 
As for the Induction Step, I made it work with the Lemma "If m <= k++, then m < k.". What helped me here tremendously is to more conscientiously formalize the argument (i.e., by writing "for all m: m<=k -> P(m)" instead of "P(m) is true for all m<=k).

Comment: @ichbinviele Cool, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

To justify step 5, you would have to prove $\forall x \forall y (y \leq x ++ \to y \leq x \lor y = x++)$. This would need to follow from a definition of $\leq$, which you did not provide in your question. Without details of this definition, we cannot proceed further.

Here is one way of proving what you wish to show. We define $x \leq y$ as $\exists z (x + z = y)$.

We want to show that $\forall x \forall y (y \leq x \land P(y) \to P(x))$. This is equivalent to $\forall x \forall y (y \leq x \to P(y) \to P(x))$. Substituting the definition of $\leq$ gives $\forall x \forall y (\exists z (x + z = y) \to P(y) \to P(x))$, which is equivalent to $\forall x \forall y \forall z (x + z = y \to P(y) \to P(z))$, which is in turn clearly equivalent to $\forall x \forall z (P(x + z) \to P(x))$.

Now we’ve finally gotten to a form we can prove using induction. Fix $x$, and proceed by induction on $z$.

Base case: we must show $P(x + 0) \to P(x)$. This is trivial, since $x + 0 = x$.

Inductive step: suppose $P(x + k) \to P(x)$. Now suppose $P(x + k++)$. That is, $P((x + k)++)$. Then $P(x + k)$. Then $P(x)$. And we’re done.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your answer. First, you seem to be proving something else than you yourself announce in the first line of your answer? Then, I'm not sure I see how either of your claims relate to step (5). Isn't it this that I need: If P(m) is true for all m <=k and P(k++), then P(m) is true for all m<=k++?

Comment: Ah, I see in retrospect that I phrased things confusingly. I did not attempt to show step 5 but instead tried to more directly prove the original proposition. To show the proposition which I stated implies step 5 is valid, we can write $y + z = x++$. We know that either $z = 0$, in which case $y = x$, or we can write $z = w++$. In the latter case, $y + (w++) = (y + w)++ = x++$, so $y + w = x$. Thus, $y \leq x$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not understanding at all. I want to show that "If P(m) is true for all m <= k, and P(k++), then P(m) is true for all m <= k++".  I don't understand where in your answer you're making reference to P, or how you take your claims to be quantified. Perhaps I'd understand you if I saw through things in the first place, but alas, I don't. (: